# btc transaction by Digital signature

Tags: transactions, signature, bitcoin-wallet-app

I have old btc wallet and I have Digital signature but i don't have Private key , Is there any way for withdraw btc from wallet just by Digital signature ?

Answer (score 1):

A signature does not allow you to recover the private key unless it was incorrectly constructed. Otherwise we wouldn't be publishing signatures everywhere as then people could steal the private keys.

Comment: I know that , I want know can i withdraw just by use Digital signature ? I want create manually transaction by Digital signature. Is it possible ?